# How can I get the native Android Editbox

Tags: android

I have created an Editbox in XML using this code:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >            
        </EditText>
```

The textbox renders like this:

[image: textbox]

How can I get the native android `EditText` with the orange borders when focused, white background etc. ?

I tried adding

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

but that only changes the background to white.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The style you are seeing is "native" for the Honeycomb (3.0) Android version, specifically, the new Holo-dark theme. The orange-borders-and-white-background look was last used in 2.3.* and has since been left behind.

Comment: oh, haha...wasn't aware of that. My android device hasn't received the update yet. Thanks

Comment: @neutrino Is there a way to display the Holo theme on pre Android 3.0 devices?

Answer (score 3):

Agree with the answer of **neutrino**: The style you are seeing is "native" for the Honeycomb (3.0) Android version, specifically, the new Holo-dark theme.

But still if you wants the EditText that you want then you need to set the style/theme inside the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
```

Answer (score 1):

when we add view's from layout, it renders from framework, then add the properties we provided . so in your code, `EditText` is native `EditText`, which varies from device to device . so if you want look and feel over a particular device make your own style for that and use it .

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem...

Try using:

```
EditText usr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
usr.setBackgroundResource(17301528);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to older versions of the `EditText` iamges (from sdk/android-8/platforms/data/res folder), place thema in the drawable folder, create a `StateListDrawable` out of it, and set the background of the `EditText` as that `Drawable`. But why bother ? Let app users enjoy the default look and feel of their device.