# Holo Theme For EditText

Tags: android, view, themes, android-edittext

I have a username `TextView` below which there is `EditText` and the same for password.I need just the `EditText` to be changed to Holo theme for respective devices.. I've  tried setting parent in `style.xml` as

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.
```

`parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText"`

but of no use..Anyone has an answer??

Hi i got the answer. the cause was activity which calls this dialog had theme android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" in manifest ..i removed and added in oncreate and there comes holo for editText!!!!

Comment: Can you post your styles.xml and manifest?

Comment: In xml 
<EditText
style="@style/EditTheme"/>

and in style.xml(i.e values-v13)i have 
<style name="EditTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
      <item name="android:background">@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.EditText</item>
 </style>

Comment: I had the same issue because of using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` for my dialog activity theme and resolved it by changing to `android:theme="@Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar"`.

Comment: Same here. I replaced in the `AndroidManifest.xml` the style `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"` and Holo was back on my EditText.

Please accept your answer as the right solution. Thx!

Answer (score 10):

use [holoeverywhere](http://www.holoeverywhere.com/) lib

OR

you can generate the edittext Holo style using [android-holo-colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) 
download the zip.then set the edittext background

Comment: I even tried that but of no use. i need edittext to be like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208283/how-can-i-get-the-native-android-editbox

Comment: Thanks but im not getting the edittext as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208283/how-can-i-get-the-native-android-editbox ..i wish i coudve showed u the images

Answer (score 2):

I had more or less the same problem. Here is my solution. =)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

            <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.EditTextStyle</item>
            <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_dark</item>
        </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.EditTextStyle"  parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/etforlogin</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `style` attribute in your `EditText` in your `XML`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"/>
```

Comment: i even tried as above below is my xml
<EditText 
  android:id="@+id/txt_password"
  android:inputType="textPassword"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop ="4dp"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_below="@id/password_text"
  android:singleLine="true"
  style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"/>

But again edittext doesnt give holo theme

Comment: if setting the theme or style isn't working your only option may be to use a custom 9 patch and set it as the background. ( https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/edit_text_holo_dark.xml )

Comment: Hi i got the answer. the cause was  activity which calls this dialog had theme android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" in manifest ..i removed and added in oncreate and there comes holo for editText!!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android developer site we are supposed to use the following theme for Activities that are displayed as a dialog if the Holo theme is desired:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout